# What is the meaning of "virtual" and "somehow" and "for whatever" in this phrase?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

This is the context:

> There seems to be only
> two kinds of answers.  Either, observation
> is needed to collapse or decohere the wave function from a probability smear to
> a single defined location, or the so-called many
> worlds interpretation, a story in itself, branches reality into innumerable
> histories and futures. Each answer is fantastical.  Either **consciousness
> somehow effects** changes the external world, or there is a **virtual** infinite
> number of total worlds, including countless
> versions of ourselves, all somehow existing
> in parallel. Fantastical is
> indeed the watch world, **for whatever is
> Closer to Truth.**

> Source: Closer to truth, Season 18, Episode 8: "Observing Quanta, Observing nature?"

The first part maybe be simple and I am dumb but I can't figure the meaning of "virtual". Does it mean "potential"? Does "somehow effects" mean "unknown effects" or something else? and can you tell me what is the meaning of the last sentence? Does it mean "because all of them makes us become closer to truth"?

Comment: Can you edit this down so you're only asking one question? Also, have you looked up those words in a dictionary? Please do that, then if you still don't understand, edit the question to tell us why the dictionary definitions didn't help. All three of the words you're asking about mean what a dictionary will tell you

Answer (score 2):

This paragraph has several errors, so please keep that in mind.

"Virtual" should really be "virtually", because it should be an adverb modifying the adjective "infinite". It means "practically". The author is saying that while the number of total worlds might not be infinite, it is infinite for all practical purposes. (By the way, he/she probably means "total number or worlds" instead of "number of total worlds".)

"Somehow effects" means exactly what the dictionary says that those two words mean. Keep in mind that the verb "effect" is a bit rare and should not be confused with the noun "effect" or the verb "affect".

I think that the last sentence contains a typo: "world" should be "word". A "watch word" is a guiding principle: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/watchword. I have no idea what the last half of that sentence means (and I'm a native speaker!).

Comment: Besides the mentioned errors, I think it should be *somehow effects changes **in** the external world.*

Comment: 'Watchword' is one, er, word. The text is riddled with errors.